# uninstalling angular globally doesn't work

Tags: command-line, package-management, nodejs, npm, javascript

How can I fully uninstall angular in Ubuntu 22.04?

```
(dimo-labeling) (dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~/dimo-labeling/frontend$ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

up to date in 164ms
(dimo-labeling) (dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~/dimo-labeling/frontend$ npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
(dimo-labeling) (dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~/dimo-labeling/frontend$ ng version
Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found.

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 17.3.2
Node: 20.9.0
Package Manager: npm 10.1.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 17.3.1
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1703.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.3.2
@angular-devkit/core            17.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.3.2
@angular/cli                    17.3.2
@schematics/angular             17.3.2
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.4.3
zone.js                         0.14.4
```

sys info

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ uname  -a
Linux ada 6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 20 16:09:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

(base) mona@ada:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: How did you install Angular? How many times? Please [edit] your question, don't use Add Comment.